# Making a custom RSS feed for my university website

Tags: go, rss

My university has a website where it posts announcements. I can't afford to miss these announcements, and at the same time, checking the website every day is kinda cumbersome. The website has no RSS feed.

The announcements are posted on a web page with the following as the format for the URL of an announcement :

```
http://example.com/news/detail/1/n
```

where `n` is the announcement ID, which is numeric.

When there is an announcement, the above web page (http://example.com/news/detail/1/180, for example), contains the announcement in the following format :

```
            <div class="middleconten">    

              <h3>
              Title           </h3>

 11 October, 2019

              <p>
                             <a href='/some/link' target='_blank'>Click here for more details</a>             
              </p>  

            </div>
```

and when there is no announcement, (that is, when a user visits a web page with a `n` value, that doesn't correspond to an actual announcement ID, http://example.com/news/detail/1/1234567890, for example), the web page is as follows :

```
            <div class="middleconten">    

              <h3>
                          </h3>

 1 January, 1970

              <p>

              </p>  

            </div>
```

How do I make a RSS feed for the website capturing the `<h3>` value, the `href` attribute, and the date?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to scrape the website regularly for new news items. You can use [goquery](https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery) for extracting the data.

The idea is simple. You need to generate the urls for the news section (fill in the value of `n`) starting from 1 and visit each url. If you find news (the structure exists), store the data. Add 1 to the `n` value to get the next ID. If the url doesn't contain news, stop and store the value of the number / ID of last successful news. The next time you can start from this ID instead of the beginning.

For example, I start from 1, I find the last successful news at ID 32. I save it somewhere. Next time I can start from 33 instead of 1.

When you have a database of the data extracted from the website, you can publish your own RSS feed from those. You can use a router like [chi](https://github.com/go-chi/chi) and gorilla [feeds](https://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/feeds) to create the rss feed.